# Delete files older than so many days in multiple zips

Tags: windows, iis, powershell

Help!

I need to scan a folder with 200gb of zipped .log logfiles and delete all the files that are over 584 days.

I have found this, and have left a reply in there, but if anyone can help in the meantime then thanks

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/ITCG/thread/793118fb-8345-4711-9710-9c3e485e6d89?prof=required

Cheers

Comment: Just to clarify, you don't want to delete the ZIP files.  Instead you want to delete log files within the ZIP that are older than 584 days, right?

Comment: That is correct keith - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using SevenZipSharp.  Backup any important data first :)

Make sure to read and change any paths that don't make sense, etc.

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("c:\lib\SevenZipSharp.dll")
[SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor]::SetLibraryPath("c:\lib\7z.dll")
$zipFiles = Get-ChildItem D:\zips\ -Filter "*.zip"
$oldDate = (get-date).AddDays(-584)

$zipFiles | % {
    $compressor = [SevenZip.SevenZipCompressor]("C:\")
    $compressor.ArchiveFormat = "zip"
    $extractor = [SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor]($_.FullName)
    $object = New-Object 'system.collections.generic.dictionary[int,string]'
    $extractor.ArchiveFileData | %{
        if ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $oldDate){
            #null index deletes the file
            $object.add($_.Index,"")
        }
        else {
            $object.add($_.Index,$_.FileName)
        }
    }
    $compressor.ModifyArchive($_.FullName,$object)
}
```